# PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService and SetExpressCheckout config / credential information

Tags: c#, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I created an app in my business account on this page:

https://developer.paypal.com/developer/applications/

When I click on the app I created I see the following:

Sandbox account, Client ID, and Secret.

I am trying to call SetExpressCheckout… but the documentation is unclear and examples are all over the map.

Basically I’m seeing things like:

```
        var request = new SetExpressCheckoutReq() { … };
        
        var config = new Dictionary<string, string>()
        {
            { "mode", "sandbox" },        // some variations of these values
            { "clientId", "fromAbovePage" },
            { "clientSecret", "fromAbovePage" },
            { "sandboxAccount", "fromAbovePage" },
            { "apiUsername", "IDontKnow" },
            { "apiPassword", "IDontKnow" },
            { "apiSignature", "IDontKnow" }
        };
        var service = new PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService(config);
        var response = service.SetExpressCheckout(request, new SignatureCredential(config["apiUsername"], config["apiPassword"], config["apiSignature"]));
```

Also, kind of weird that credentials go into both the PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService and the actual SetExpressCheckout call.

What are (and where do I get) the correct values for the above config? (the request itself I have pretty much figured out)

Note: PayPal support told me that I need to use Reference Transactons in order to charge varying amounts over potentially varying times without subsequent user interaction, if that is relevant.

I would love to see examples of this with the most recent API's if anyone has that information as well.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SetExpressCheckout is a legacy NVP API

- For sandbox, it uses credentials from the "Profile" of a sandbox account in https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Faccounts%2F
- For live, https://www.paypal.com/api

---

ClientID/Secret credentials are used for the current v2/checkout/orders REST API, which at the moment does not have any public documentation for vaulting or reference transactions; it is for one time payments. You can find information for a server-side integration at  https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/

If you are using this REST API integration, create two routes --one for 'Set Up Transaction' and one for 'Create Transaction'. Then pair them with this approval flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

Comment: So... if I want to charge varying amounts over potentially varying times without subsequent user interaction... then I need to use the legacy NVP API?

Comment: For anyone else who is looking at this... on the developer accounts page (first link in the above answer)... on either of the sandbox accounts there are three dots on the right, click this and choose View/edit account... here you will find a tab named API Credentials and this will show you Username, Password, and Signature.